# Java creating long strings

Tags: java, android, string, long-integer

I have a little problem and cant solve it myself.
Check this little piece of code:

```
private void setCommand(String cmd, String uid) {
    String b64cmd = new String(Base64.encode(cmd.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));

    try {
        StringBuilder bulitString = new StringBuilder("http://adwi.net84.net/zserver.php?r=setcmd&pwd=123&uid=");
        bulitString.append(uid);
        bulitString.append("&cmd=");
        bulitString.append(b64cmd);


        URL url = new URL(bulitString.toString());
        System.out.println(bulitString.toString());
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.getInputStream();
```

It just creates and sends request to the server. Everything works fine if the cmd is short enaugh. Debugger prints (this is android app btw)
[image]

And everything works fine, as excepted. But if I pass something longer to this function I get exception java `EOFexception`

it looks like that. I dont know, it looks like this string breaks into two strings? What should I do to fix this? Thanks for spending your time.. 
[image]

Comment: Hmm, maybe a limit in system.out.printLn. Try using Log.d. This is the preferred way to print to debug in android.

Comment: @weston but it doesn't matter, even if I comment out System.out.println it still throws this exception.

Comment: OK, well the exception comes from what happens next anyway. So what is after the system.out line?

Comment: @weston Oh, sorry I added missing lines.

Comment: I have no idea why it works for shorter strings, and doesnt for longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My theory is your base 64 encoding is inserting new lines. The server only receives one line and gets upset because it represents a fragment of base64 data.

So to disable this use  NO_WRAP rather than DEFAULT.